# How to interrupt sleep() without using multiple threads in C?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a terminal application for Linux which uses the ncurses library to update the terminal with a 1 second sleep in between each update. I want to keep this sleeping behaviour, but at the same time I want the program to exit immediately when I hit the q-key, not getting a potential 1 second lag. Therefore I need a way to interrupt `sleep()`. I am aware that `alarm()` will do that for me, but for that I need another thread which calls `alarm()`. This does not mix well with ncurses which is single-threaded. Is there anything that might help me achieve this?

My code is something like this:

```
void run() {
    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_things; ++i) {
            if (getch() == 'q') return;
            
            printw("Something");
            refresh();
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use sleep. Use a 1-second timeout when calling `getch()`. If the user enters something before the timeout, you'll process it immediately. Otherwise, `getch()` will return after 1 second if the user doesn't type anything.

Comment: Use `poll()` or `select()` on stdin fd with timeout and call `getch()` only if there is data on stdin.

Comment: Using ncurses own `timeout()` before `getch()` is the simplest solution I think. Brilliant, cheers @Barmar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Barmar. Use ncurses `timeout(1000)` before `getch()`. Like this:

```
void run() {
    while (1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_things; ++i) {            
            printw("Something");
            refresh();
        }
        timeout(1000);
        if (getch() == 'q') return;
    }
}
```